# Function that returns a 1D array but takes two arguments in Fortran90

Tags: arrays, function, compiler-errors, fortran, fortran90

I am trying to define a function in a program that takes two 1D arrays `x` & `y` and then returns a 1D array. Please see below:

```
PROGRAM sumtest

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, DIMENSION(10) :: x, y
INTEGER, DIMENSION(10) :: funct
INTEGER :: i

DO i=1,10
   x(i)=i
   y(i)=10-i
END DO

y = funct(x,y)

DO i=1,10
PRINT*,y(i)
END DO

END PROGRAM sumtest

FUNCTION funct(x,y)

IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, DIMENSION(10), INTENT(IN) :: x,y
INTEGER :: i
INTEGER, DIMENSION(10) :: funct

DO i=1,10
     funct(i)=x(i)+y(i)
END DO

END FUNCTION funct
```

However when I try to compile I get the error message:

```
sumtest.f90:14:

y = funct(x,y)
1
Error: Incompatible ranks 1 and 2 in assignment at (1)
```

I'm just wondering what I need to do to correct this, or if it's just not possible to put two arguments in a function that returns a 1D array?

Comment: By `INTEGER, DIMENSION(10) :: funct`  in the main program you actually declared a local array. Learn to use modules as the link shows. Making the function an internal function would work too in this particular simple case.

Comment: And just following up on Vladimir's comment in more general terms learn why having an interface in scope when you invoke a subprogram is without exception (tempting fate...) a good idea, and why you should always, Always, ALWAYS do this when writing modern Fortran.